# jQuery Tag-It beforeTagAdded event with email validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tag-it

I used [jQuery Tag-It](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) to make the email field to be tag-like. I try to check whether the email is valid or not from server side, in my case, `api.php`, which makes response like:

```
{"status": "OK"}
```

or

```
{"status": "NG"}
```

I would like to reject invalid emails from adding into the input field after checking, so I put an AJAX post to the API call. But the event `beforeTagAdded` requires immediate boolean instead of an asynchronous reply. Here is my code:

```
$('input[name=txt_email]').tagit({
    beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
        if(!ui.duringInitialization) {
            $.post('api.php', {
                'request': 'check_email',
                'entry': ui.tagLabel
            }, function(response) {
                if(response.status == 'OK') {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    },
    onTagExists (fn, callback) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I change my code to reject the invalid codes?

---

**UPDATE** I know I can set the AJAX call to synchronous mode, but it is not advised as it is bad in terms of User Experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used tag-it for my project,hope this will resolve your issue.

my solution:

```
beforeTagAdded: function(event,ui){
                    var temp = ui.tag.text();
                    var t11 =  testcall();
                    alert("++++>>>"+t11);
                    return t11
                   }
function testcall(){
    var result = true;//personal choice to set the boolean value
    $.ajax({
            'url':'/app/test',//your own url
            'type':'POST',
            'data':{'zx':123},// any data if needed
            'async':false, // this is important for this task
            success:function(response,Status,code){
                    alert("success >>");
                    result = false
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    alert("error");
                    console.log(exception);
            }
    });
    alert(result);
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as said in my question, setting synchronous mode for AJAX call (Synchronous XHR) is deprecated. I need another solution.